# How to add an external library in Mobile Angular UI framework?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, frameworks, gulp

I'm just getting started with Mobile Angular UI (http://mobileangularui.com/), but can't figure out which steps I need to take in order to include another external library. I have my lib files in the
bower_components folder, which is on the same level as the src folder in the file structure. I need to include js, css and image files in the project.

For example, I am using the bootstrap class *glyphicon-plus*, which exists in the bower_components folder (bower_components/bootstrap/less/ and bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/). After building the project, the class is not present in the target directory (www/css/).

Looking at the Gulpfile, I see no transfer of CSS files from source directory to target directory happening, only LESS files from the src/less/ folder are handled there. Anyway, the Gulpfile is only intended for default settings. It states at the beginning of the file: "Please use config.js to override these selectively:".

In config.js, there is a section showing how to add 3rd party Javascript components:

```
config.vendor.js.push('.bower_components/lib/dist/lib.js');
```

However, there is no corresponding array for CSS files.

If you look in index.html, the file references to CSS files are all adapted for the target folder (www/), as they all start "css/", which is not a valid reference in the source folder.

How do I add css, fonts, images from bower_components and src folders to the project, so that they appear in the target?

Comment: [wiredep](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep) can help

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem, you can modify the gulpfile.js file adding the following lines:

First, you define a "bower_css" empty array:

```
vendor: {
    js: [
      './bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      './bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      './bower_components/mobile-angular-ui/dist/js/mobile-angular-ui.js'
    ],

    fonts: [
      './bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.*'
    ],

    bower_css: []
  },
```

Then, you build a task to copy the css files to dist folder:

```
/*==================================
=            Copy bower_components css files          =
==================================*/

gulp.task('bower_css', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.vendor.bower_css, {base: './'})
  .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(config.dest, 'css/')));
});
```

So, in config.js file, you add the following lines, for example for sweetalert:

```
config.vendor.bower_css.push(
    './bower_components/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css'
);
```

In that way, in the html file you can load the corresponding css file because are over the www directory. Is a custom solution but worked for me. I hope that solution be helpful to you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this is a very nice example of how to read the javascript file and wrap it inside a service factory, the example uses d3 but it could be any library, the service return the actual instance of the library you can inject it and use it as you like.

```
angular.module('d3', [])
  .factory('d3Service', ['$document', '$q', '$rootScope',
    function($document, $q, $rootScope) {
      var d = $q.defer();
      function onScriptLoad() {
        // Load client in the browser
        $rootScope.$apply(function() { d.resolve(window.d3); });
      }
      // Create a script tag with d3 as the source
      // and call our onScriptLoad callback when it
      // has been loaded
      var scriptTag = $document[0].createElement('script');
      scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript'; 
      scriptTag.async = true;
      scriptTag.src = 'http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js';
      scriptTag.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 'complete') onScriptLoad();
      }
      scriptTag.onload = onScriptLoad;

      var s = $document[0].getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
      s.appendChild(scriptTag);

      return {
        d3: function() { return d.promise; }
      };
}]);
```

you'll need to wait on the resolution of the promise to return by using the .then method on the d3Service

let's say you are using the service into a directive:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', ['d3'])
  .directive('barChart', ['d3Service', function(d3Service) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        d3Service.d3().then(function(d3) {
          // d3 is the raw d3 object
        });
      }}
  }]);
```

take a look to this [tutorial](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html) as reference.

that's a cool workaround, if you don't like to just include the reference on the HTML, also you can add the reference using an async loader library take a look to the project [angular seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/app/index-async.html) that might be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

By external libraries, do you mean other javascript dependencies such as jQuery?  Also, into the project, do you mean the HTML files?  If you are using bower, you can reference other installed javascript dependencies the same way you are with mobile Angular UI.

When you do bower.init it sets up a bower.json file as well as a bower_components folder which contains your dependencies.  If you are using jQuery (and have done bower install --save jquery), add this line to your HTML document:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js">
```

This is the crude way, if you want to load javascript dependencies through some sort of loader / build tool which will minify your JS files as well, look into a build tool such as grunt or gulp.  Here's a link to those tools:

http://bower.io/docs/tools/

CSS files can be included in your HTML document with a link tag:

```
<link href="bower_components/path/to/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Comment: The question is specific to the "Mobile Angular UI" framework. I am familiar with generic HTML, Javascript and Bower. I have of course tried adding file refs like you suggest here, but it doesn't seem to work. There is something more to it.

Comment: Hrm..strange, there should be nothing specific to the framework.  Can you try accessing your js file by typing out the path in the browser?  Hard to tell without seeing your project, but this should work to load any script, asset or CSS file.  Maybe there is a path issue.  Did you try this link out?  http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-mobile-angular-ui/